# Excel Sumif Array

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, array

I'm trying to use an array formula with sumif and know the correct format is along the lines of 
    =sum(sumif(A:A,B:B,{"hello","hi"})),

However when I try to use `>` or `<` than operators, the formula doesn't work.

```
=SUM(SUMIFS($T:$T,$M:$M,{">"&2,"<"&10000}))
```

Can someone please help me with how this formula (while using arrays) would work? Thank you and I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Generally, we expect questions like this to ***explain*** what you are trying to accomplish and show some example data (posted *as text,* not a screenshot).

Answer (score 0):

No need for array.  In this instance you want `AND` not `OR` like in the other situation, B is either `hello` OR `hi`.  With the second you want all between `2` AND `10000`.  SUMIFS does `AND` naturally:

```
=SUMIFS($T:$T,$M:$M,">2",$M:$M,"<10000")
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, you're using array constants, not array formulas in this case. Your problem is that you're using the & and closing your quotes too quickly... The array constant should look like this.. {">2","<10000"}

The full formula would be:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS($T:$T,$M:$M,{">2","<10000"}))
```

Not sure what your use case for this is, however I'm fairly positive you don't want to SUM **and** SUMIFS, otherwise it will sum everything in $T:$T and then add the sum of everything that fits your sumif statement criteria.